# How to measure voltage of a track lighting fixture?

Tags: voltage, multimeter, light

My house has track lighting that takes MR16 halogen bulbs. I would like to measure the voltage being put out by the fixture using a multimeter. I removed one bulb, set my multimeter to V-DC and inserted each probe into each hole of the fixture where the bulb would go. Nothing happens on the multimeter. Am I simply not making contact or am I doing something more fundamentally wrong?

Comment: Are you sure it is DC? Did you try the AC volts range?

Comment: I don't think I have ever seen an MR16 fixture that uses DC

Comment: Thanks I tried using the V-AC setting on the multimeter but it reads 0.17V, that doesn't seem correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most MR16 tracks are powered by transformers. Since there is no benefit in rectifying the AC the manufacturers don't bother.

Be aware that the transformer will have some internal resistance and should be designed so that when all the bulbs are in the voltage will be correct. i.e., When unloaded the transformer voltage will be higher than the full-load voltage.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdXX6B.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Equivalent circuit for MR16 lighting rack.*

The effect of this is that if you remove a bulb the voltage will rise a little. If one lamp fails the others then run hotter and will probably also fail sooner than rated life.

Comment: Thanks for the diagram, I see from the comments that I should actually be measuring AC, however following the same technique I described in my question but using the V-AC setting on the multiemeter should that work to measure the AC voltage? I tried it and I only get 0.17V which seems wrong.

Comment: Yes, it seems wrong. We're expecting 12 V AC. Can you test the meter in a wall socket? Meter and leads OK? (Test leads using ohms or continuity setting.) Are the probes getting in far enough in the MR16 sockets?